# variable can't change in fuction after mysql query

Tags: javascript, node.js

i couldn't find any working solution to this problem i want to update mi queryResult variable.

But when i do console.log(queryResult) outside of function it gives me like 50 lines of information about query but when i do console.log in function it print object with data what i need.

> ```
> var queryResult;
> con.query('SELECT * FROM topics;', (err, result, fields) =>{
> queryResult = result;
> return queryResult
> });
> console.log(queryResult)
> ```

Comment: you are dealing with an async function here, so the callback is executed after the logging

Comment: @ArunPJohny It gives me same result